# Interpreting sentences containing data

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, statistics

Is the construction correct?

> The daily actual irradiation was lower than the day-to-day target 48% of the time in the entire month.

How do you interpret this sentence?

Comment: A target for irradiation was set for each day, and the actual irradiation was lower than this 48% of the time. If the actual irradiation is measured by taking samples at equally spaced intervals, then 48% of these measurements would be below the target set for the day. This question is more suited to ELL.

Comment: Is there any number of days that resolves to 48% of 28,  29, 30, or 31?

Comment: @TimR, 15 out of 31 is 0.483870.., so yes, to 2-figure accuracy.

Comment: "of the time in the entire month" is not clear.

Comment: The string 'daily actual' is idiomatically 'actual daily' (I'm assuming 'actual radiation' isn't a technically-defined fixed phrase). Peter's rewrite is clear. I'd use 'Over the month, the  irradiation on any given day was lower than the target for that day 48% of the time' or  'Over the month, the  irradiation on any given day was lower than the fixed daily target  48% of the time', whichever is intended.

Comment: It's not "of the time in the entire month", it's "48% of the time", covering a period given by "in the entire month". Some punctuation would help although I'm not certain what.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think they phrased it that way to distinguish "actual irradiation" from "target irradiation".

Comment: @Barmar Very few hits for "daily actual radiation" shows this is non-standard.

Comment: The text is badly written / ambiguous. It could be that ***48% of the time*** is the target itself, and that the actual value was lower than this for the entire month. OR (logically, more likely) that actual values were lower than ***some unspecified target value*** for 48% of the time during that month.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the obvious interpretation is "This text was not written by a competent Anglophone".

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand this is that there's an acceptable total amount of irradiation for any day, and this is called the *target* because the goal is to have less than this.

The actual total irradiation was measured each day during the month. And 48% of these measurements were lower than the target. For a 31-day month, this would mean that it was lower on 15 days.

Grammatically it would be possible for there to be distinct targets for each day of the month, and 15 out of 31 of them were lower than their specific targets. But in the context of radiation, it seems unlikely that targets would depend on the day of month. On the other hand, if the context were store sales, it would be likely that there would be differences depending on the day of week.